# Ordering by day of week - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, python-datetime

I want to create a weekly calendar according to created schedules by admin. Days of week should be displayed horizontally, and each of schedules under according day of week, vertically. Now my code works like [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t49Ik.png). But I want to display, for example, monday meeting vertically in one column and so on. here are my codes:

`views.py:`

```
def index(request):
    available_times = Available.objects.all().order_by('available_date')
    context = {
        'available_times': available_times
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

`models.py`:

```
class Available(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    message_to_participiant = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    available_date = models.DateField()
    available_hour = models.TimeField()
    is_scheduled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

`index.html`:

```
<div class="container">
        {% for meeting in available_times %}
        <div class="meeting-box">
            <h4>{{ meeting.available_date|date:"l" }}/{{ meeting.available_date }}</h4>
            <p>{{ meeting.available_hour }}</p>
            <p>{{ meeting.description }}</p>
            <p>{{ meeting.message_to_participiant }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: you can filter and order `DateField`s using `__week_day`, like `available_date__week_day` [see this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/)

Comment: @Sajad, It's ok, but how can I show them in the same row according to week day ?